# Android DIP size wrong

Tags: android, size, density-independent-pixel

This one is bedeviling me.   What am I overlooking?   I want a button exactly one inch wide, on any density screen.  I declare it in the layout like this:

```
<Button  
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:width="160dip"
android:text="How wide?"
/>
```

What I get is a button that is exactly 7/8ths of an inch wide on all screens, not the expected 1 inch.  Is the difference maybe the margin or padding around the button?  If so, how to set that to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dip are based on virtual densities, not actual physical densities. For instance, on a T-Mobile G1, the device's display physical density is around 180dpi, but we treat it as a 160dpi display. Android currently uses 3 "density buckets," 120, 160 and 240. Each device uses whatever is most appropriate. If you want accurate physical measurements, use physical units like in, mm, etc.

Comment: True, but also it seems there is always some empty spacing around a button, even if you set the margin and padding to 0. If you compare it with an ImageView you will see the difference.

Answer (score 4):

What about this ?

```
android:layout_width="1in"
```